Creating a printable label using html
Ok, I’m trying to design my own label for candle wax melts for my new business. It’s a 2.5x3” label and I want my business name at the top and in the middle center I want the outline of a rectangle with Soy Wax Melts in cursive running through the bottom right corner line of the rectangle. I want to be able to put the name of the scent in the center of the rectangle and add additional text further down. I’m trying to figure out where exactly do I type this html code to get it to create this to transfer it onto a printable label. How do I tell it what size I’m wanting the center triangle? I’m confused 
I haven’t actually tried anything because I have no clue where to even begin. When I search for label it’s giving me something entirely different not an actual sticker label like I mean.

HTML might not be the best tool here. I would recommend using design software instead. Good free open source tools I recommend are Inkscape and Krita. Canva is a simpler online tool that could also work.
